# jVectorMap double execution on onRegionClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I am using jVectorMap librery to generate map and from map when i click on any location the console.log() hitting double always. Please check the jVectorMap properties bellow. How can i prevent console.log() double execution? any thing wrong i am doing here?

Js Code:

```
$('#chartprescriptionMaps').vectorMap({
                    map: 'usa_en',
                    backgroundColor: null,
                    color: '#E6ECF1',
                    borderColor: '#000',
                    borderOpacity: 0.80,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    enableZoom: true,
                    showTooltip: true,
                    selectedColor: null,
                    hoverColor: null,
                    colors: states,                   
                    onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
                        console.log(code);//this log executing 2 times every single click 
                    },

                    showLabels: false,
                    onLabelShow: function (event, label, code) {
                        if (statesData[code])
                            label.html('<div class="map-tooltip">' + statesData[code] + ' referrals in ' + code.toUpperCase() + '</div>');
                        else
                            label.html('<div class="map-tooltip">' + code.toUpperCase() + '</div>');
                    },
                });
```

Comment: try adding `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` inside handler

Comment: onRegionClick: function (event, code) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        console.log(code); }, I tried this but still same issue. always executing double on single click